# Navigating from one HTML page to another onsubmit

Tags: forms, flask

I managed to open an HTML form page, and now I'm trying to navigate from that page to an output HTML page. once a user submits the form a validation function runs. If it returns true the output HTML page should be redirected to.

The error I get with the code I got now is

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'output'. Did you mean 'to_output' instead?

I looked at many solutions and tried many of those yet didn't manage to navigate to the results page. What I got so far:

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def to_form():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/output', methods=['POST'])
def to_output():
    return request.form['pepsurf_form']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**form tag in index.html**

```
<form name="pepsurf_form"
    ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"
    ACTION="{{ url_for('output') }}"
    METHOD="POST"
    onsubmit="return validate_and_continue()">
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've called your route function `to_output` (line 10, `def to_output():`) and hence `{{ url_for('output') }}` should be `{{ url_for('to_output') }}`.